# No settings in System Settings app in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, system-settings

Title says it all, really. For some reason, there are absolutely no settings available in the System Settings app:

[No settings :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s041f.png)

Even if I go into the settings via other apps, they still don't appear. When I installed `gnome-system-settings`, they showed up in that app but didn't work.

I've tried reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop`, but I'm pretty sure that only works for 14.04.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: when you say you tried reinstalling ubuntu-desktop, did you re-install the task? To do this, run "sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^" (note the caret on the end, it's important). Run that, does anything new get installed/upgraded?

Comment: Nothing apart from ubuntu-desktop itself, so it doesn't really do anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, figured it out, and the answer is kind of irritating.

DON'T HIDE THINGS IN THE UNITY MENU USING A MENU EDITOR. That was the sole reason. Once I unhid the settings, they all came back.

I assume the app reads from the menu to find out what settings to have, and if it doesn't exist in the menu, it doesn't exist in the settings either. That's kind of annoying, to be honest; I would have thought it'd make more sense to have that be independent, but oh well.

Comment: can u help heere? https://askubuntu.com/questions/933095/kdes-kwins-system-settings-missing-icons-16-04

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem i think, there were only a few options on the settings. I found out that XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP can be set to something wrong, so the settings doesnt appear. I created a script which just unsets the XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP variable, and then it works.

```
#!/bin/sh
unset XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
unity-control-center
```

Comment: No, that doesn't appear to have done anything at all... It's not that I can see some but not all, I can't see a single setting.