# KDE's KWin's System Settings missing icons, 16.04

Tags: 16.04, kde, system-settings, kwin

as I remember, everything was there on 14.04, after upgrading to 16.04 I have only these below, what can I do to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Try re-installing `systemsettings` - `sudo apt-get install systemsettings`.

Comment: I tried from synaptic reinstall (didnt work), then I tried "complete  removal" and installed again, to no avail :/

Comment: Do you get any warnings or error messages with `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`? If so, you may need to post the entire terminal output here.

Answer (score 0):

Using synaptic, I did install `kubuntu-desktop` package and all the icons showed up, but I am not sure if that is overkill as my system was an Ubuntu iso.

To try to avoid any problems, I also did reinstall `ubuntu-desktop` while keeping kubuntu.

there were some errors, I read the log, they seem to not be any serious problem.

I just reboot and it is working great (kde in all seems to be working better like decorations and other things), but I am not expert on it, so I appreciate any more info on what I actually did (that worked).